# How to properly deference a char** pointer passed as an address to functions?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, c-strings, dereference

I am writing a program that uses char ** to setup a multidimensional array.
I then pass the address of the char ** to another function to play with.

How do I properly deference ** pointers after they have been passed via address to another function?

> ERROR
> array of c string
> Segmentation fault

```
int test(char *** strings){
    puts(*strings[0]);
    puts(*strings[1]);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {

    char arr[][25] =
    { "array of c string",
    "is fun to use",
    "make sure to properly",
    "tell the array size"
    };
    
    
  char ** strings = (char**)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
  
  strings[0] = (char*)malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(strings[0], arr[0]);
  
  strings[1] = (char*)malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(strings[1], arr[1]);
  
  test(&strings);

  return 1;
}
```

*Mallocs are casted incase someone plugs this into a C++ playground

Comment: I would rather avoid `***` https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
int test(char *** strings){
    puts((*strings)[0]);
    puts((*strings)[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Because `[]` binds more tightly than `*` and you need to dereference first. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 2):

There is no great sense to pass the pointer `strings` to the function `test` by reference because the pointer itself is not changed within the function.

And the return type `int` also does not make a sense.

The function can be declared and defined at least like

```
void test( char ** strings )
{
    puts( strings[0] );
    puts( strings[1] );
}
```

and called like

```
test( strings );
```

If nevertheless you want to pass the pointer by reference then the calls of `puts` could look like

```
    puts( ( *strings )[0] );
    puts( ( *strings )[1] );
```

That is at first you need to dereference the pointer to get the original pointer `strings` declared in `main` and then apply the subscript operator to the obtained original pointer,

Answer (score 1):

You can use array notation, it looks nicer, IMO:

```
int test(char ***strings){
    puts(strings[0][0]);
    puts(strings[0][1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Let's say you want to change a character:

```
strings[0][1][1] = 'z';
```

This would change the 2nd character(index 1) of the 2nd string, it would then be:

```
iz fun to use
 ^
```

If the goal was just to access the data, and not modify it, passing the pointer by value would be enough.